# Getting exception while using the Generic Array?

Tags: java, generics

I was using the following code to create a generic array of lists to mix up different types of lists:

```
List<Integer>[] intLists = (List<Integer>[])new List[] {Arrays.asList(1)}; 
List<? extends Object>[] objectList = intLists;
objectList[0] = Arrays.asList(1.01);
int n = objectList[0].get(0); // class cast exception!
```

But it gave me a cast exception.
How can I work around this?

Comment: do you understand what this line does List<? extends Object>[] objectList = intLists; ? You are still using a List<Integer>

Comment: That code can't give you a ClasscastException, since it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this gives a compile error though it apparently is creating a raw array of lists and while storing it seems the compiler cannot detect that its an array of List (it cannot detect the type of list - so perhaps it just interprets it as a raw list) and hence does not throw an error and when you try and retrieve the element into an integer it fails while trying to cast a double into an int. This is not a correct usage.

I believe you can do `(Integer) listArray[0].get(0)` but it will cause precision loss post the floating point.

Answer (score 0):

The type of objectList[0].get(0); is Double so you have to convert it to an int.
The following works:

```
int n = ((Double) objectList[0].get(0)).intValue();
```

But depending on you use case you code is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store a double value in an integer variable.  You can't do that.  So just store it in a double instead:

```
        List<Integer>[] intLists = (List<Integer>[])new List[] {Arrays.asList(1)}; 
        List<? extends Object>[] objectList = intLists;
        objectList[0] = Arrays.asList(1.01);
        double n = (double) objectList[0].get(0); // Make it a double :)
```

Comment: If there is a requirement that it be stored as an `int`, this does not answer the question.